# Why does RandomAccessFile use int as offset

Tags: java, int, long-integer, random-access

I am writing some data access test implementation and I need random access to file content. Here's the code:

```
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");
final byte b[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(source);
randomAccessFile.write(b, (int) offset, size);
```

where offset has type long. 
Why doesn't RandomAccessFile provide method:

```
public void write(byte b[], long off, int len)
```

?

How to override this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `seek` method.

The offset in `write` is an offset into the array. Arrays have `int` offsets. There have been proposals for "long arrays", but were these implemented, you'd still need an overload.

Mapped files in NIO have a problem in that the equivalent `MappedByteBuffer.position` for some reason only uses `int`. See [CR 6347833](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6347833) (9 votes).

Comment: +1. Interestingly, the JDK `MemoryMappedBuffer`, which is Java's sole interface to mmap, only takes an `int` in its `position()` method, which makes it kind of wimpy in the same way that te OP was concerned about. Go figure.

Comment: So, it's not an offset within file? Then int is ok, and I'll alwasy call .seek(), thanks.